# Toggle Checkbox settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, toggle

I've a table of elements and each has a line has a checkbox to opt-in or out. As the list of items can be very long i want to offer a "global" checkbox to tick all checkboxes or untick them based on the setting of this global checkbox.
I have created jQuery code that does exactly that, but unfortunately only one time. I can't toggle the settings again and again. Any thoughts why? Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
jQuery('#ci-firmware-assign-toggle-checkbox').click(function(){
    if(jQuery('#ci-firmware-assign-toggle-checkbox').is(":checked")) {
        jQuery('tbody .ci-firmware-assign-checkbox').each(function(){
            if(!jQuery(this).attr("checked")) {
                jQuery(this).attr('checked', true);
            };
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('tbody .ci-firmware-assign-checkbox').each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).attr("checked")) {
                jQuery(this).attr('checked', false);
            };
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You should use `.prop()` instead if `.attr()` and I think you code can be reduced to `jQuery('#ci-firmware-assign-toggle-checkbox').click(function(){
 jQuery('tbody .ci-firmware-assign-checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('#ci-firmware-assign-toggle-checkbox').change(function(){   
   $('.ci-firmware-assign-checkbox').prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this

```js
jQuery('#ci-firmware-assign-toggle-checkbox').click(function(){   
if(jQuery('#ci-firmware-assign-toggle-checkbox').is(":checked")) {
    
   $( '.ci-firmware-assign-checkbox' ).prop( "checked", function() {
        return true;
    })
    
} else {
   $( '.ci-firmware-assign-checkbox' ).prop( "checked", function() {
        return false;
    })
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='ci-firmware-assign-toggle-checkbox' type='checkbox' />Toggle All<br/>
<input id='1' type='checkbox' class='ci-firmware-assign-checkbox' />Checkbox 1<br/>
<input id='2' type='checkbox' class='ci-firmware-assign-checkbox' />Checkbox 2
```

And it seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#ci-firmware-assign-toggle-checkbox').click(function(){
    if(jQuery('#ci-firmware-assign-toggle-checkbox').is(":checked")) {
        jQuery('tbody .ci-firmware-assign-checkbox').each(function(){
            if(!jQuery(this).**prop**("checked")) {
                jQuery(this).**prop**('checked', 'checked');
            };
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('tbody .ci-firmware-assign-checkbox').each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).**prop**("checked")) {
                jQuery(this).**removeProp**('checked');
            };
        });
    }
});
```

attributes -> HTML - do changes in html only

properties -> DOM - do changes in dom javascript state objects